# MySQL EXPLAIN showing ALL type although INDEX exists

Tags: mysql, select, join

I ran the below query using `EXPLAIN`

```
EXPLAIN SELECT form.id           AS `Reference No.`, 
               department.name   AS `Department`, 
               section.name      AS `Section` 
FROM   form 
       JOIN department 
         ON form.deptid = department.id 
       JOIN section 
         ON form.sectid = section.id
```

Does type `ALL` in the first row indicate that there is going to be performance issues?

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+
| id | select_type |   table    |  type  | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |         ref          | rows |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | form       | ALL    | deptid,sectid |         |         |                      |  779 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | department | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | wfs-test.form.deptid |    1 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | section    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | wfs-test.form.sectid |    1 |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------+------+
```

Comment: Check out this link. Has a nice explanation on this topic..http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/mysql-using-explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for MySQL to use the index when it gets data from table `form`. Because the query doesn't have any `WHERE` clause, potentially all the rows from table `from` will be included in the final result set. More, because there is no `ORDER BY` clause, any order of the rows is good enough. This is why MySQL gets the rows directly from the table, without consulting any index.

Adding a `WHERE` condition could trigger the use of an index if an index that contains (some of) the fields involved in the `WHERE` conditions exist (and the fields, put in the correct order, are the leftmost columns included in the index).

Adding an `ORDER BY` clause (without `WHERE`) on fields from table `form` could also trigger the use of an index when all the fields selected from table `form` are contained in the index. It will change the type from `ALL` to `index` which means it will do a full scan of the index instead of the data rows to get the data it needs. While this is still a full scan, a `full index scan` usually runs faster than a `full table scan` because less data is loaded from the storage and parsed (the index is usually smaller than the table data).

More information about this can be found in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html).

The entire section ["8.2.1 Optimizing SELECT Statements"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-optimization.html) is worth reading to better understand how to write faster queries.